# How do I select a value with XSL based on text in node?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following code snippet:

```
<span>
<
<span class="start-tag">meta</span>
<span class="attribute-name">name</span>
="
<a class="attribute-value">Creator</a>
" 
<span class="attribute-name">content</span>
="
<a class="attribute-value">John Doe</a>
" 
<span>/</span>
>
</span>
```

I'm trying to use XSLT to select the value of the 'attribute-value' node after I find the 'attribute-value' node that has 'Creator' in the text.  Any ideas how I can do this?  Ultimately, I want something that's like

```
<content name="Creator">John Doe</content>
```

Comment: Is `attribute-value`, a value of attribute `@class` that always belongs to element `<a>`? Does the code snippet also contain the characters `<`, `=`, `"`, in them or they are added to format the output?

Comment: That snippet is not well-formed XML, the opening `<` in the second line is not possible in XML. So you will first need to explain how you parse and feed that snippet to XSLT at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, you probably looking for an Xpath like that :

`a[@class='attribute-value' and .='Creator']/following-sibling::a[@class='attribute-value'][1]`

Where `a[@class='attribute-value' and .='Creator']` is selecting the 'Creator' `a` node.

Then `following-sibling::a[@class='attribute-value'][1]` will select its following siblings with the `@class='attribute-value'` and keeping only the first one.

But, as told in the comments, your sample is not valid xml. The plain '<' should be escaped (usually with <). And your expected results should be more explicit, is this your whole input file ? What are you trying to achieve (you give an expected result but a unique node is probably not your real need) ?

Nevertheless, the XPath given should do the job and will select the expected node based on your sample. But as your question lacks of details, be aware that the different predicates used may need some improvements based on the input complexity.